# How to receive data from one server to another using PHP

Tags: php, android, json, google-cloud-messaging

I want to get JSON data from an server and store it to database on my server.

I bought API that returns json, which means that server is not mine but I want to take that data and store it to my server.

How to call API, receive data and store it to my server?

P.S. That API only allows access from 5 IP addresses and I want to use it for android app. Instead of getting data directly from that server to android phone, I have to store that data to my server and then call GET method on my server to receive results on the android phone. This way I could even use GCM.
It doesn't have to be php script. If you have better idea or solution please let me know.

Comment: `$json = file_get_contents("http//theapi.com/path/to/endpoint");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http//example.com/path?query"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So this one line will call the API and store its content to this variable $json? And how do I put it in table inside my database on my server?

Comment: I can't help you much with that. It depends on the database software you use and on the database schema. You will use SQL INSERT/UPDATE commands, but how exactly you do that varies depends on many things.